# How to be notified if WCF Duplex session is prematurely closed

Tags: wcf, callback, duplex

I have a publish/subscribe scenario in WCF using net.tcp and Duplex callbacks.  I have a number of clients that subscribe to the service, and this works fine.  However, sometimes a client will close without unsubsribing (Client computer goes to sleep, computer crashes, network connection is aborted, etc..), this causes an exception to be thrown when I callback via my callback list.

Now, I can certainly catch the exception and remove the offending callback, but this seems less like an exception scenario to me and further along the lines of "expected behavior".

Is there an event that gets fired on connection close that will notify me so that I can remove the callback from my list?  Consider that this is net.tcp and not HTTP, so connection state should be known.

Clearly the framework knows the connection has been closed and disposed because the exception is something along the lines of "attempt to call a disposed object".

EDIT:

I should point out, that this is not a long running transaction. It's a long running connection in a publish/subscribe scenario. Basically, the callback is used to notify transient subscribers of various events as they happen. Each event is isolated and not long running.

Comment: I'm curious what the duration of your WCF conversation is if it is possible for your clients computers to go to sleep. I'm decently versed in WCF, and from what I know, Duplex services were not intended to be used for long-running, persistent transactions for the very reason you are encountering.

Comment: What something was 'designed for' and what it's often used for are often quite different.  I require a long running connection, in which i utilize a heartbeat message to keep the connection alive.  Since WCF offers no other options for a long running connection, I have to make due with this or rewrite my app to not use WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while, this is from memory so I could be wrong, but I think perhaps if you make an IEndpointBehavior that goes an pokes at the DispatchRuntime to add an IInputSessionShutdown, then you can get notified when the session channel ends.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.inputsessionshutdownhandlers.aspx

Comment: Looks promising.. i'll experiment and where this goes

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm also catching the exception and then removing client.